# What does "gaierror: getaddrinfo failed" mean and how can I correct it?

Tags: python, smtplib

```
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-dc15e9c5d9c3> in <module>
     17     # creates SMTP session
     18     #s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) no 2f
---> 19     s = smtplib.SMTP('auth.smpt.1and1.co.uk', 587)
     20     # Authentication
     21     s.starttls()

gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: First guess would be that your system can't resolve that hostname.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what that means. The system had been running fine so I have no idea what could have caused this. I am not tech savvy at all

Comment: ~\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py in __init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout, source_address)
    249 
    250         if host:
--> 251             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
    252             if code != 220:
    253                 self.close()

Comment: my deposit invoices are sending fine but this is the error I am getting when trying to send the final, does anyone know what I can do to resolve this

Comment: `getaddrinfo` is a method shipped typically with Linux systems that resolves DNS names to IP.  The error you are getting is, as Andrew commented, because your system can't resolve that hostname.  From a terminal, try doing an `nslookup auth.smpt.1and1.co.uk`

Comment: @HeatherMatthews actually I think I see your problem, line 19, it should probably be (guessing) `auth.smtp.1and1.co.uk` NOT `auth.smpt...`.  SMTP stands for "simple mail transfer protocol" so I'm guessing that's what it is.

Comment: Hi the code has always been written this way and still seemed to work but I thought this as well so I changed it and it brought a whole different error up

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b0d3e13459c1> in <module>
     44         # open the file to be sent
     45         filename = outfname
---> 46         attachment = open(outpath_dep, "rb")
     47         # instance of MIMEBase and named as p
     48         p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\hbroa\\12072-FINAL.docx'